# Python add to list in nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

While trying to append lists to a dict I've stumbled upon something I do not quite understand. I am trying to append to the value of a nested dict but my output is all weird.

For the inputs each `list[index]` corresponds to `other_list[index]`.

**INPUTS**

```
timestamp    = [1450625399, 1450625399, 1450625399, 1450625399, 1450625399, 1450625399, 1450625399, 1450625399, 1450625399, 1450625399]
instrument   = ["AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "HPQ", "AAPL", "HPQ", "AAPL", "HPQ", "AAPL", "AAPL"]
side         = ["sell", "sell", "buy", "buy", "buy", "buy", "buy", "buy", "buy", "sell"]
price        = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8.8, 4.44, 7, 5, 6]
size         = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**METHOD**

```
import datetime
import collections

def timestamp_to_date(stamp):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def dailyOHLC(timestamp, instrument, side, price, size):
    out   = []
    dates = collections.defaultdict(dict) 

    for i in range(len(timestamp)):
        try:
            dates[timestamp_to_date(timestamp[i])][instrument[i]].append([side[i], price[i], size[i]])
        except:
            dates[timestamp_to_date(timestamp[i])][instrument[i]] = [side[i], price[i], size[i]]
    print dict(dates)
```

I am probably missing something obvious but my current output is

`output @print = {'2015-12-20': {u'AAPL': [u'sell', 1, 1, [u'sell', 10, 2], [u'buy', 2, 3], [u'buy', 3, 5], [u'buy', 4.44, 7], [u'buy', 5, 9], [u'sell', 6, 10]]}}`

While I expected something like this

`expected @ print = {'2015-12-20': {u'AAPL': [[u'sell', 1, 1], [u'sell', 10, 2], [u'buy', 2, 3], [u'buy', 3, 5], [u'buy', 4.44, 7], [u'buy', 5, 9], [u'sell', 6, 10]]}}`

My problem lies with the nested list being in format `[... ,[...],[...]]` instead of `[[...],[...],[...]]`.

Comment: The output currently is `[a,b,c, [a,b,c], [a,b,c]]` while I'd like to iterate over it in a different way namely foreach list in the list... so I was looking for an output like `[ [a,b,c], [a,b,c], [a,b,c] ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your timestamps are all the same for a single transaction, then you don't have to keep converting it to a date each time.

But, the main issue is here:

```
except:
    dates[timestamp_to_date(timestamp[i])][instrument[i]] = [[side[i], price[i], size[i]]]
    # ______________________________________________________^----------------------------^
```

You're missing these extra braces.